# Div Height 100% Too Short In Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, android-browser

I'm having a problem with setting the height of a slide-out menu to 100%. When I view it in a browser it works great, however in mobile not so much.

The problem appears to be that when the browser calculates the height of the screen it includes the url bar which disappears as the user scrolls down. This is causing a div with `height: 100%;` to come up about 50px short.

A demo of the site is available here: http://nickersonweb.com/sandbox/flexiweb/

There are a couple problems I am addressing at the moment (such as why the fixed header doesn't slide to the right with the rest of the body in mobile browser but does on my pc, and why you can still scroll the width height of the body when the menu is open in mobile browser but not on my pc). I'm just focusing on the height issue right now.

Below is the HTML coding as well as the CSS for mobile browsers (or desktop browsers set to less than 480px width).

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Website Title</title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="robots" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="generator" content="" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function menuButton() {
            if( document.getElementById("htmlBody").className == "menuClosed" ) {
                document.getElementById("htmlBody").className="menuOpen";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("htmlBody").className="menuClosed";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body id="htmlBody" class="menuClosed">

    <div id="margins">

    <!----- HEADER ----->
    <div id="header">
        <div class="margins">

            <!----- LOGO ----->
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="">WebsiteName</a>
            </div>
            <!----- /LOGO ----->

            <!----- NAVBAR ----->
            <div id="navbar">
                <div class="left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 8</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right" onclick="menuButton()"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar-button" onclick="menuButton()"></div>
            <!----- /NAVBAR ----->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!----- /HEADER ----->

    <!----- BODY ----->
    <div id="body">
        <div class="margins">
            body text
        </div>
    </div>
    <!----- /BODY ----->

    <!----- FOOTER ----->
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="margins">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
    <!----- /FOOTER ----->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    body {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
        -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
        transition: all 200ms linear;
    }

    #margins {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    #header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 90;
        overflow: visible;
        height: 60px;
    }

    #logo {
        top: 15px;
    }

    #navbar .left {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 75%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #dddddd;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
        -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
        transition: all 200ms linear;
    }

    .menuClosed #navbar .left {
        left: -75%;
    }

    .menuOpen #navbar .left {
        left: 0px;
    }

    .menuClosed {
        left: 0px;
    }

    .menuOpen {
        overflow: hidden;
        left: 75%;
    }

    .menuOpen #navbar .left li {
        float: none;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .menuOpen #navbar .left a {
        color: #444444;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .menuOpen #navbar .right {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 75%;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25 );
        -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
        -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
        transition: all 500ms linear;
    }

    #navbar-button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: url('../images/mobile-nav-button.png') no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #body {
        margin: 70px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

}
```

I've searched similar questions but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: It shows up fine for me when I resize the browser. Is there a particular mobile browser you're testing on?

Comment: Android I am using. I tested on a friends iPhone and it worked better on his.

The problem I think is on Androids mobile browser the URL bar isn't fixed. When you scroll down it disappears. I think this is causing the size to come up short because its including the height of the URL bar in the initial measurements.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed